# ArrayList and Array difference

Tags: .net, arrays, arraylist, msdn

With reference to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41107z8a(VS.71).aspx), It is stated that **"You can set the lower bound of an Array, but the lower bound of an ArrayList is always zero"**

If i declare an array a[10], the lower bound is always a[0].

Is this the lower bound specified there? If yes, How can we set the lower bound of an array, Since the index of an array always starts with a[0].

Or is the lower bound stated in the link is something different?

**Note:** I know the link point to the contents of **.NET Framework 1.1** but still curious to know what exactly they have mentioned.

Comment: FYI, the `ArrayList` class is deprecated as of .NET 2.0. It should not be used. Instead, `List<object>` should be used if the list needs to contain objects of arbitrary types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array with a non-zero lowerbound using [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx).

Note that you won't be able to cast that to a `Foo[]` (where `Foo` is the relevant type) unless you also make it multidimensional. There are two types of array inside the CLR - a *vector* (zero based, single dimensional) and an *array* (can be multi-dimensional and have non-zero lower bound).

A `T[]` in C# always corresponds to a vector, whereas a `T[][]` corresponds to an array. So you can do:

```
int[][] rectangle = (int[][]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),
                                       new int[]{2, 2}, // lengths
                                       new int[]{-1, -1}); // lower bounds
```

but this will fail:

```
int[] rectangle = (int[]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),
                                       new int[]{2}, // length
                                       new int[]{-1}); // lower bound
```

Likewise you can't cast it to `IEnumerable<int>` or `IList<int>` - although you can iterate over it with `IEnumerable` just fine.

Personally I would avoid using non-zero lower-bounded arrays like the plague. They're slow, and painful to work with.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - nice to see you again on a question i answered aswell ;)

Comment: If i am wrong please clear me, as the answer states, a single dimension array is a vector always? yet size of the vector can be varied as like arraylist which isn't possible with array.

Comment: @Sri Kumar: No, look at the second example - it's a single dimensional array, but it's not a vector. Note that this is "vector" in the CLR sense, not a class called Vector like in Java. And no, the size of a vector can't change.

Answer (score 3):

The lower bound in C# and VB.NET is always at `0`. Visual Basic 6.0 and older allowed for variable lower bounds. They removed it for the rewriting of the language for .NET.

Here is an article that goes into detail of how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx. Look for "Creating Arrays with a Non-zero Lower Bound"

Comment: Is that still true in Visual Basic.NET? (I'm not a VB programmer)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311333

Comment: @Andrew I guess not - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23s0z8fy%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I believe that VB silently subtracts one from any array access expression. It doesn't actually create 1-based arrays as far as the CLR is concerned.